# Autentificar mi APP NodeJS en GitHub

Tags: nodejs

Tengo una app que recupera licencias segun los repos de mi organizacion. Pero actualmente estoy teniendo problemas al obtenerlos, ya que me devuelve error 404 y ninguna licencia. Por lo que vi es un tema de que hay que autentificar la app en github para que te permita hacer mas de 60 request por hora. El unico ejemplo que pone GitHub es https://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/

y mi problema con esto es que no hay ningun ejemplo en nodejs y soy algo novato con este lenguaje. Si alguien me podria dar una mano o guiarme mas o menos como hacer para autentificar mi app.

```
getFromGithub: function(allRepos, callback){
    var self = this;

    console.log(self.settings.gitToken);


    var apiRequest = api('/repos/' + self.settings.org + '/' + self.repo + '/contents/package.json', {
        token: self.settings.gitToken
    });

    apiRequest.on('data', function(response) {
        self.reposParsed = JSON.stringify(allRepos);

        var packageJSON = new PackageJSON(self.settings, self.reposParsed);
        packageJSON.parseFromString(response.content, function(){

            //Log the requests of proyect.
            const output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
            const errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
            const logger = new Console(output, errorOutput);
            logger.log(res);


            self.getLicenseTree(packageJSON, function(err){
                if(err)
                    return callback(err, null);

                self.licenses = packageJSON.list;

                callback(null, self.licenses);
            });
        });
    });

    apiRequest.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err, null);
    });
},
```

Y este es el codigo donde se obtienen.